# Can I use ELMAH for errors in my UI as well as BizTalk or WCF services?

Tags: wcf, biztalk, elmah

So I understand that ELMAH is pretty awesome and a great tool for ASP.
I'm seeking a tool for centralized error handling spanning disparate technologies across the enterprise.  ELMAH might be suitable if you can log exceptions to it from BizTalk or a WCF service... provided that it does more than just catch unhandled ASP exceptions.

Anybody familiar with what I'm talking about and care to give me a little education?

Comment: please use the title field as a summary of your question, not an excited announcement that you have a question.

Comment: Righto.  Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

ELMAH is intended for logging exceptions from ASP.NET applications. You can specifically log handled exceptions via the `ErrorSignal` class, so it does more than log unhandled exceptions.

If you're looking for something more robust and enterprisey, you should check out the [Microsoft Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc467894.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a bundle, Robert.  I'm integrating with BizTalk Server, so the enterprise library might just be the way to go.